# Does this limit of integral exist?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f : (0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Suppose that the limit $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1 f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$ exists. Then, can we show that both limits $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1 f^+(x) \mathrm{d}x \text{ and } \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1 f^-(x) \mathrm{d}x$$ exist, where $f^+(x) = \max\{f(x), 0\}$ and $f^-(x) = \max\{- f(x), 0\}$? Thanks!

Comment: Please define $f^{-1}$ and $f^{+1}$

Comment: I believe $f(x)=\frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{x}$ should give a counterexample